# Regex to extract titles from the text

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, text-extraction

Can anyone help with the regex to extract the text phrases after 'Title:' from the following text: (have just bolded the text to clearly depict the portion to be extracted)

```
Title: Anorectal Fistula (Fistula-in-Ano) Procedure Code(s): 



Effective date: 7/1/07

Title:

2003247 

or previous effective dates) 



Title: 

ST2 Assay for Chronic Heart Failure 

Description/Background 

Heart Failure 

HF is one among many cardiovascular diseases that comprises a major cause of morbidity 
and mortality worldwide. The term “heart failure” (HF) refers to a complex clinical syndrome .
```

I am using the regex: `(?:Title: \n+(.*))|(?:Title:\n+(.*))|(?<=Title: )(.*)(?=Procedure)`

However, it doesn't seem to capture the terms correctly! I am using Python 2.7.12

Comment: It seems that the [regex matches what you need](https://regex101.com/r/tWSH05/1).

Comment: A bit more contect (more of your code) would be helpful

Comment: How do you retrieve the matches?

Comment: How isn't it capturing them correctly?

Comment: Anand005, if you keep silent, we won't be able to help you. Do you mean you have other line endings? Try replacing `\n+` with `[\r\n]+`. Or better - [`Title:\s*(.*?)\s*Procedure|Title:\s*(.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/a8DXbK/1)

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ekH6il

Comment: Thank you all! Yeah, you're right! The regex does work correctly! Another problem in the code was misinterpreted as being due to wrong regex! Sorted! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using

```
 Title:\s*(.*?)\s*Procedure|Title:\s*(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a8DXbK/1).

*Details*:

- `Title:` - literal text `Title:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols as few as possible up to the first
- `\s*Procedure` - 0+ whitespaces + the string `Procedure`
- `|` - or
- `Title:\s*` - `Title:` string + 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 2: zero or more any chars other than linebreak symbols as many as possible (the rest of the line).

[Python code](http://ideone.com/QJiZjR):

```
import re
regex = r"Title:\s*(.*?)\s*Procedure|Title:\s*(.*)"
test_str = ("Title: Anorectal Fistula (Fistula-in-Ano) Procedure Code(s):\n\n"
    "Effective date: 7/1/07\n\n"
    "Title:\n\n"
    "2003247\n\n"
    "or previous effective dates)\n\n"
    "Title:\n\n"
    "ST2 Assay for Chronic Heart Failure\n\n"
    "Description/Background\n\n"
    "Heart Failure\n\n"
    "HF is one among many cardiovascular diseases that comprises a major cause of morbidity and mortality worldwide. The term “heart failure” (HF) refers to a complex clinical syndrome .")
res = []
for m in re.finditer(regex, test_str):
    if m.group(1):
        res.append(m.group(1))
    else:
        res.append(m.group(2))
print(res)
# => ['Anorectal Fistula (Fistula-in-Ano)', '2003247', 'ST2 Assay for Chronic Heart Failure']
```